# Cannot download from Internet Explorer 8

Tags: internet-explorer-8

[image]

I am not able to download from IE8 and the message as described in the image above pops up.

I've searched a lot and learnt that it's something to do with the Hkey values, but not exactly found a solution pertinent to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

It means the required action is disabled via group policy.

I assume it's running various executables that is disabled, not the downloading.

Comment: Hi Greg , thanks for the reply .This issue though is I am the admin of this system . My assumption is that something that i installed in the recent past screwed up the Hkey values .

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;Q310049) FixIt from Microsoft, i know it points to having a problem within outlook but it's a reg key fix linked to opening things from websites (hyperlinks).